# What format can be used for big data in SQL?

Tags: sql, bigdata

It is just simple question as in title.
My data row is 1,650,461 but excel or CVS only can export til 1,048,576.
Is there better format?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think MS Access might be a better tool choice.  Excel is not recommended for text data.  It can change the values if you're not careful.  Plus, the limit of rows is way too small.

BTW big data is not 1.6 M rows.  That is big for Excel, but any other tool can handle that easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can have CSV format, which is not having any row limitation like EXCEL.
You can also go for TSV format also.

For example, in our Azure Data Lake analytics, we used to read data like given below. [Reference USQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/functions/operators/extractors/extractors-csv)

```
 @Trips =
      EXTRACT date    DateTime,
          driver_id   int,
          vehicle_id  int,
          trips       string // Array
       FROM "/Samples/Data/AmbulanceData/DriverShiftTrips.csv"
       USING Extractors.Csv(encoding: Encoding.[ASCII]);

  OUTPUT @Trips 
  TO "/Output/ReferenceGuide/BuiltIn/UDOs/extractorCsv_DriverShiftTrips.csv" 
  USING Outputters.Csv();
```